# Detect JavaScript comments starting with **! using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried a lot doing this using RegExp.

Pattern: `\*.*\*!`

Test text:

```
/**!
 * Plugin Name 1.0.0
 * @author  Name
 */

/*! Test */

/* Test */

/************************************************************************/
/******/ /* Test */
/******/
/*!*********************!*\
  !*** ./index.ts ***!
  \*********************/
```

Link for test:
https://regexr.com/6eoa0

It works great and matches the first comment and that's what I need, but for some reason, it matches the other two comments.

How can make it detect comments that start with `**!` (in one line).

Comment: Use a javascript parser - regex is not powerful enough to cover every scenario here.

Comment: This part `\*.*` matches _zero_ or more asterisks, then followed by `\*!` — so `/*!` is zero-asterisks then '*!' which matches. You want _at least two_ asterisks which would be `\*\*+!` -- plus matches _one or more_ instead of _zero or more_. (I'm assuming you also want `/*****!` — if you want _exactly_ two it's just `\*\*!` no need for `+` or `*`)

Comment: @ASDFGerte — the pon̷y he comes... https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/238884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/\/\*\*![^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\//g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/diaaWb/1). *Details*:

- `\/\*\*!` - a `/**!` string
- `[^*]*` - zero or more chars other than asterisks
- `\*+` - one or more asterisks
- `(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `[^\/*]` - any char other than a `/` and `*`
  - `[^*]*` - zero or more chars other than asterisk
  - `\*+` - one or more asterisks
- `\/` - a `/` char.

Comment: The question isn't fully clear about where these comments reside, but i am assuming javascript syntax. There are a lot of small issues, e.g. fake comments in string literals: `'/**!'/* */`. While those maybe can be dealt with in an extremely complex regex (what about `'\'/**!*/'`?), a real brick wall are nested template literals, as you can embed more template literals inside one, and each embed can include real comments (`\`${\`/**!\`/**/)}\``). It's hardly ever done, but valid javascript.